# Type NgxGalleryModule does not have' ɵmod 'property

Tags: angular, npm, ngx-gallery

I use angular 11. I typed npm install ngx-gallery --save in the terminal and loaded the ngx-gallery package. Then I made the import process in the module.ts file as stated in the documentation. at first it gave the error on the [link](https://github.com/lukasz-galka/ngx-gallery/issues/330).I converted the renderers in the lines specified in the terminal endings to renderer2. This problem has disappeared. Now in the console 'Type NgxGalleryModule does not have' ɵmod 'property.' I have followed exactly what is said in the documentation. how can i solve this problem?

Comment: I am facing similar issue with ngx-leaflet-draw during unit testing any components which references the module.

Comment: I got it resolved by running ngcc. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67202351/1926476