# ngx-leaflet-draw: Importing module which does not have a ɵmod property

Tags: angular, leaflet, leaflet.draw, ngx-leaflet, ngx-leaflet-draw

> Importing LeafletDrawModule which does not have a ɵmod property

I am seeing this error during my unit testing(jest).

The code works fine when I run the ng application. Leaflet draw function works perfectly.

```
Angular: 11
@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet: 8.1.0
@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-draw: 7.0.0
```

This error happens when unit testing components referencing  LeafletDrawModule

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

After running `ngcc` on the module folder the issue resolved itself.

Incase you get ***ngcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command*** you haven't configured the nodemodule binary path in `PATH`. You can get execute it from `[project_path]\node_modules\.bin\ngcc`

**or**

If you have the postinstall configured in package.json,

```
"scripts": {
   .
   "postinstall": "ngcc",
   .
}
```

run `npm run postintall`.

Comment: Thanks! that solved it for me.