# Error: e does not have a module def (ɵmod property)

Tags: angular

During my unit test i see this error
`Error: e does not have a module def (ɵmod property)`

I updated to angular v14(

```
"@angular/cli": "~14.0.0",
```

) and nx workspace (

```
"@nrwl/workspace": "14.4.3",
```

)

The error does not specify which module is causing the problem:

```
Error: e does not have a module def (ɵmod property)

    at transitiveScopesFor(....)
```

test File:

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let mockOAuthService;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    // mocks
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
      value: jest.fn(() => {
        return { matches: true };
      }),
    });
    mockOAuthService = { logout: jest.fn(), checkAuthentication: () => Promise.resolve(null) };

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent, AddEntriesButtonComponent],
      imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        HsMaterialModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        RightsModule,
        AuthModule.forRoot(),
        NgxsModule.forRoot(),
      ],
      providers: [{ provide: AuthService, useValue: mockOAuthService }, MediaObserver],
      teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false },
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app successfully', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I have been stuck with this for days and i cannot find solution anywhere.
I have tried deleting node_module and npm ci and other steps in : https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/13958

It did not help.

I already have this in package json

```
"scripts": {

"postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2020 browser module main && node ./decorate-angular-cli.js",
}
```

as stated in [ngx-leaflet-draw: Importing module which does not have a ɵmod property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67202351/ngx-leaflet-draw-importing-module-which-does-not-have-a-%c9%b5mod-property)

Comment: Did you try npm ci?

Comment: yes i did..i deleted node_modules and did npm ci

Answer (score 1):

just include pipe in `declerations` array instead of `imports`

Answer (score 0):

you are looking at the problem in the wrong place. the error is not in the test file. I assume you have created a custom component which you want to reuse in multiple pages. If you are using a shared module do not forget to include "entryComponents:" and if you do not have a shared module then make sure the custom component is in the "entryComponents:[customComponentName]"
here is an example:

```
//shared module

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    CommonModule,
    MomentModule,
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  declarations: [CustomComponentName],
  entryComponents: [CustomComponentName],
  exports: [CustomComponentName]

})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot() {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    }
  }
}
```